# Match with regular expressions words between colon (excluding colon)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:
"I went to :Rome: last night, now I'm in :Florence:"

I want to get with regex the word between the colon, excluding them, so I want this output
Rome Florence
At the moment I wrote this :(.*?):\g but it keeps colons in.

Comment: At the end, by replacing the old string I need to have "I went to Rome last night, now I'm in Florence"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex will look for a word (on word boundry) which will be prefixed and suffixed with the colon `:`

```js
var input = "I went to :Rome: last night, now I'm in :Florence:";
var regex = /(?:\:)\b(\w*)\b(?=\:)/g
var arr = []
while (m = regex.exec(input)) arr.push(m[1]);
alert(arr)
```

**Edited**

As JavaScript flavor of RegExp does not support many features I would advise to change the regex for replacement to following :

```
var input = "I went to :Rome: last night, now I'm in :Florence:";
var regex = /:([\w]+):/g
var replaced = input.replace(regex, "$1")
```

Comment: It keeps in the first colon, which is not what I need, I am doing tests here: [link](http://regexr.com)

Comment: @Ferex I have added version better suited in JavaScript for replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var arr = [],
    re = /:([^ :]+):/g,
    input = "I went to :Rome: last night, now I'm in :Florence:";

while ( m=re.exec(input) )
   arr.push(m[1]);

console.log(arr);
//=> ["Rome", "Florence"]
```

Comment: It is pretty easy fix if space is not to be allowed in captured text, see edited one.

Comment: Not really see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eM0hA8/3) where 20€ should not be selected.

Comment: First of all `[^:| ]` is wrong, you need to read about character class. Second how do you know **20€ should not be selected**?

Comment: Hahaha - I need to read nothing. If you do not like it, then give the solution it works. The author said the regex should match `the word between the colon` which is along the case I am looking for, and your solution does not help.

Comment: First of all you and I haven't read OP's mind so better not to assume anything. In your character class you have `[^:| ]` which has extra pipe which is not needed. It is up to you if you want to read & learn about it or spend time on commenting here.